# Error on callback when running a recursion function using async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion, node-async

I try to execute a recursion through a tree, in order to exec `node_func` for each node in the tree. `node_func` also returns the next values in the tree under `[values]`.

I use `async.eachSeries` which get a list of the nodes in the next level of the tree.
The function runs successfully over the first branch of the tree, but at the leaf where I have the stop condition, I try to call the `callback` but it's `undefined`.

The code:

```
function clone(a) {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
}
var searchNext = function(params, callbackSN){
    var seParams = clone(params);
    node_func(seParams,function(searchRes){
        //Stop Condition - return
        if (searchRes["nextFeature"] != 1){
            return callbackSN(); //Stop Condition
        }
        var values = searchRes["values"]
        var paramsArr = []
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            var seParams2 = clone(seParams);
            seParams2["value"].push(values[i]["value"])
            paramsArr.push(seParams2)               
        };

        async.eachSeries(paramsArr, searchNext, function(err){
            return callbackSN(err)
        });         
    })
}

//init search
var params = {"value" :[]}
searchNext(params,console.log)
```

When I run it, it runs over the first branch, and when it gets to the "Stop Condition" I get the following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Pointing to the line:

`return callbackSN(); //Stop Condition`

At the Stop Condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in the original code :

```
function clone(a) {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
}
var searchNext = function(params,db, callbackSN){
    var seParams = clone(params);
    node_func(seParams,db,function(searchRes){
        //Stop Condition - return
        if (searchRes["nextFeature"] != 1){
            return callbackSN(); //Stop Condition
        }
        var values = searchRes["values"]
        var paramsArr = []
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            var seParams2 = clone(seParams);
            seParams2["value"].push(values[i]["value"])
            paramsArr.push(seParams2)               
        };

        async.eachSeries(paramsArr, searchNext, function(err){
            return callbackSN(err)
        });         
    })
}

//init search
var params = {"value" :[]}
searchNext(params,console.log)
```

The second variable "db" at `node_func` cannot be called from the async, so it made the confusion.

I added the "db" variable at the parent function as a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
return callback(err)
```

You are invoking the callback function, but it is not defined in your code. I guess you want to call the callbackSN function.

```
return callbackSN(err)
```

Comment: You are right. I have updated the code. But, still, it doesn't get there. As I wrote it fails on the "Stop Condition" line.

Comment: It is difficult to see where the problem is, because I do not know what the rest of the code does (as the node_func function) Could you post all the code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `node_func` is irrelevant, but I will try to create  a sample function I can easily share.